# When does the following sequences of random variables follow SLLN?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Find the values of the constant $c$ in each case so that the Strong Law of Large Numbers holds for each sequence of independent random variables $\{X_n\}$:
>
> (i) $P(X_n=\pm c^n)=\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1},\space P(X_n=0)=1-2\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}$
>
> (ii) $P(X_n=\pm n^c)=\dfrac{1}{2n},\space P(X_n=0)=1-\dfrac{1}{n}$

I don't have any idea on what to do because I only know how to do for iid r.v.

Comment: Well, one thing that can go wrong is if the sequence of arithmetic means diverges with positive probability. In both cases this will tend to occur when $c$ is large enough.

Comment: I understand that $E(X_n)=0$ for all $n$. I don't however understand what to do when just independence is given.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. When I say the sequence of arithmetic means I mean the random variables $S_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. If $E[|S_n|]$ is not bounded then there is no hope of having the SLLN apply. This will occur for large $c$ in your examples. (Note that I haven't said anything about what happens if $E[|S_n|]$ *is* bounded.)

Comment: Doing a little work for you, in the second case, $E[|S_n|]=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{c-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{c-2}$. This will blow up if $c \geq 1$. So you only have any hope of SLLN holding if $c<1$.

Comment: I see. Well, I can say that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Var(X_n/n)<\infty$ then I can find the corresponding values of $c$ so that this sum converges. This in turn ensures a.s. convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/n$ which by Kronecker's lemma shows that $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k/n\to0$ a.s. But this is just sufficiency. Can we say something like necessary condition?

Comment: That depends: what range of values of $c$ do you get by that approach? For instance, in the second case, it would not surprise me if the approach you've described tells you that you have convergence for $c<1$. Then the non-convergence for $c \geq 1$ is more-or-less "free".

Comment: I see. I suppose that showing $E|S_n|$ blows up is crucial.

Comment: Err...sorry, I made a slight error earlier. $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{c-1}$, for $c \neq 0$, is $O(n^{c-1})$, and for $c=0$ is $O(\log(n)/n)$. So it goes to zero for $c<1$, blows up for $c>1$, and the situation for $c=1$ is not so simple.

Comment: It still doesn't matter.  Thank you for showing me that we need to consider the expectation of the mean also. Because we wouldn't want that to blow up. I'll keep this is mind. I believe the first problem can be tackled in a similar way, right?

Comment: I think so, yes. But I think the first problem is actually a bit easier (in the small $c$ case) because you get nice geometric series estimates.